# How to get a position of the div? jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How would you get the position of a div?

Here is what i got so far

```
 <script> 
 $(document).ready(function() { 
 $("#draggable").draggable({ grid: [50, 20] }); 
 }); 
 </script> 
 <div id="drag_border"> 
 <div id="draggable" style="width:500; height:800">Drag me</div> 
 </div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any of the events you can use [`ui.position`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/), for example:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({ 
  grid: [50, 20],
  drag: function(e, ui) {
    var top = ui.position.top;
    var left = ui.position.left;
  }
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5wxkk/)

Comment: Just curious. How'd you get the custom URLs on jsFiddle?

Comment: @Peter - When you create a fiddle when logged in, that's how it generates the links when you fork

Comment: Thanks for the response. For some reason it isn't doing that for me when logged in using OpenId... I'll see if I can figure it out. Are you an alpha tester?

Comment: @Peter - They have to make your account manually at the moment....public accounts will be there in beta :)  OpenID is for SO, jsFiddle is a totally separate thing :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) method.